# Twitter API - getting pinned Tweets

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

So I'm trying to use the Twitter API to get the pinned Tweet from a user's timeline, which Twitter tells me should be possible https://twittercommunity.com/t/update-to-twitter-developer-labs-retrieve-pinned-tweets/128688.

I've printed out all the info to try to find pinned_tweet_id, but naturally it's not there. Weirdly, it does show the first non-pinned Tweet on the timeline, but that could be found through GetUserTimeline anyway.

```
twitter_handle = "@TwitterDev"
user = twitter_api.GetUser(screen_name=twitter_handle)
print(user)
```

Twitter's docs merely say

pinned_tweet_id (Note: to request fields for this tweet, use expansions=pinned_tweet_id for default fields id and text, and &tweet.fields=created_at,public_metrics,… for additional fields)

but adding expansions into GetUser() throws the "unexpected keyword argument error".

Any ideas? I realise I could go a roundabout route and use selenium, but I want to keep it all in the API, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: You need to be using the new Twitter Developer Labs API, and a library that supports that. It’s completely new API methods and data formats.